# Put conditional and function call in one line

Tags: coffeescript

Is there a way (hopefully clean) that i can do the same thing here without assigning the state value?
I have been having problems with the if condition returning booleans (instead of a function) when the if condition is on the same line.

```
onItemChanged = (event,ui) ->
  input_element = event.target
  list_id = input_element.getAttribute('list_id')
  state = if input_element.checked
            onItemChecked //function of int -> nothing
          else
            onItemUnchecked //function of int -> nothing

  state (list_id )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
onItemChanged = (event, ui) ->
  input = event.target
  state = if input.checked then onItemChecked else onItemUnchecked
  state input.getAttribute('list_id')
```

Or even:

```
onItemChanged = ({target: input}, ui) ->
  state = if input.checked then onItemChecked else onItemUnchecked
  state input.getAttribute('list_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you'd consider it cleaner, but you could also call the result of the `if` expression directly:

```
onItemChanged = (event,ui) ->
  input_element = event.target
  list_id = input_element.getAttribute('list_id')
  (if input_element.checked then onItemChecked else onItemUnchecked) list_id
```

Or maybe just call the `onItemChecked` or `onItemUnchecked` inside the `if`:

```
onItemChanged = (event,ui) ->
  input_element = event.target
  list_id = input_element.getAttribute('list_id')
  if input_element.checked 
    onItemChecked list_id
  else 
    onItemUnchecked list_id
```